# How can i create my own custom URL for my website i'm hosting

Tags: apache, server, dns

I have set up an apache server on my computer and I am hosting a website off of it. My url that is accessible via other computers on the network is my ip followed by the file path. For example 192.1.1.1/blog/index

I would like to be able to have users access my website by typing studioblog.com or just http://studioblog. How could i achieve this?

I have tried editing the localhost via /etc/hosts file but to no avail

Comment: to make the website accessible to others, rent a hosting + a domain name to any "hosting provider". just "studioblog" won't work as a public internet domain name, but you cna set it up for a local network.

Comment: how would i go about setting if for a local network without having to rent a domain ?

Comment: for a local network, you don't need to rent a domain, true. It means your site won't be accessible by the internet (except if you set up a VPN connection). Now, to set up your local network, it depends of course on how your network is configured. Basically, you can assign a fixed IP to the computer that is hosting your server, and then set up the host file on every client to point the name "studioblog" to the IP of this machine. Maybe that is the point where you were doing a mistake : the "hosts" file is to be setup on *the client computers*, not at the server level.